# Elastic Search searchlite min_score

Tags: elasticsearch

How would I specify a min score in elastic search lite?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/search-lite.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html

right now I am trying 
`http://localhost:9200/_search?q=${encodeURI(this.search_input)}&size=500&min_score=1 but it is throwing an error.

thanks

Comment: You should show the error that is being thrown. My guess is that `min_score` is not a valid parameter in the URL query string. Also can you show the full URL that you're hitting (i.e. with the generated query string)